# Total of DATEDIFF from different ROWS with different DATES

Tags: sql, sum, rows, datediff

I'm trying to get the total days of datediff from different items. There are few conditions:

1. Some dates are before the StartDate '2020/04/01'
2. Some dates are after the EndDate '2020/04/30'
3. Delivery Dates could be before/after or between Start/End dates
4. Collection Dates could be before/after or between Start/End dates

For example, items have different Delivery and Collection dates between StartDate and EndDate or they could be the same but if the Delivery and Collection dates are not in between Startdate and EndDate so the result should be the datediff between StartDate and EndDate.

*In my case the StartDate is 2020/04/01 and EndDate is 2020/04/30*

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '2020/04/01'
SET @EndDate = '2020/04/30'

select distinct itemno,

sum ( case when deliverydate between  @StartDate and  @EndDate  and collectiondate between @StartDate and @enddate then
        (DATEDIFF(day,deliverydate,collectiondate)-(DATEDIFF(week,deliverydate,collectiondate)*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, deliverydate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, collectiondate) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end)

         when deliverydate between @StartDate and @enddate and collectiondate >= @enddate then
        (DATEDIFF(day,deliverydate,@EndDate)-(DATEDIFF(week,deliverydate,@EndDate)*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, deliverydate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,@EndDate) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end)

        
         when deliverydate <= @StartDate and ci.docdate#5 >= @EndDate then
        (DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate)-(DATEDIFF(week,@StartDate,@EndDate)*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @endDate) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end)

        when deliverydate <= @StartDate and ci.docdate#5 between @startdate and @EndDate then
        (DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,ci.docdate#5)-(DATEDIFF(week,@StartDate,ci.docdate#5)*2))+1-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,ci.docdate#5) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday,  @StartDate) = 'Saturday' then 1 else 0 end)

        
        
        else 0 end

) as Daysonhire,

from Stock


where itemno = '001127'
group by itemno
```

MY RESULT IS   **Daysonhire = 30**

AND THE DATES FROM THE DATABASE ARE **deliverydate 14/04/2020 collectiondate 16/06/2020**
So the **result should be 12 or 13 working days**

Comment: Sorry I have never said Thank you or Hi, so rude!

Comment: Sounds like `datediff(day, greatest(@StartDate, deliverydate), least(@enddate,collectiondate)`

Comment: Hi, no. It is not working

Comment: can you specify your SQL, server version, some sample data from your stock table ?  (oracle,mysql,SQLServer,Azure), and add the corresponding tag... what is ci.docdate#5 ?